# Microsoft Teams: How to open external URL with custom notification in activity feed?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Microsoft Graph allows to [send notifications to a user's activity feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications). Good, we needed that and as of 2021 it's possible.

There is one restriction though regarding what happens when the user clicks or taps the notification. You can specify a URL to link to but it has to start with "[the Microsoft Teams domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#example-3-notify-a-user-about-an-event-using-a-custom-topic)". So it can [deep-link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) to chats, channels, files etc. But external web sites?

My use case is generating notifications for an external ticketing system and linking to those tickets upon choosing the notification. So the notifications need to link to a non-teams domain. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could post to a channel somewhere, or post to the user 1-1, and then link to the post using the notification

Comment: Yes that would work. Still hoping to spare the user this extra hop and extra click.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have any feature to link a notification to non-teams domain. Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.